# How to develop login/registeration in SPA application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

My application has single page and implemented ngRoute for all tabs navigations.
Now, need to implement login and register. Post to that only, it should navigate to all tabs navigations.

I have confusion for below points:
  1) Do I have to create create another one new page for login and register And post to login, do location.href and redirect to existed page which has all tabs navigations.  (Is this valid for SPA based application?).

2) Or Do I have to add login and reigsteration on same page where all tabs navigation existed. (in this option, I am not sure, how I can hide all tabs until login or any security threats).

application is developed using angularjs and web api.

Please provide help here to show best approach.

thanks

Comment: I would recommend having an interceptor to validate all outgoing requests. From this you can get the state of authentication too. For login/signup, you have another route. 

If you have some tabs that should be accessed only after login, you can always send a redirect from the backend to the login screen.

Comment: It means, login/register to keep on same controller and each request validate through some gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is use ui.router instead of ngRoute.

Next is add root scope state change listener in app.run.js file

and add authentication check in there like below

```
var userInfo = authenticationService.isAuthenticated();

var isLogin = toState.name === "login";

if(isLogin){
    if(userInfo) 
        e.preventDefault();
    return;
}
if(userInfo === false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login');
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: I will try with ui.route appraoch.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the login and register routes in the same page. Angular JS provides a $cookie service where in the cookies can be set.

Before the user log's in or register's, you can check for the cookie and hide the tabs using the directives which angular provides, for example: ng-if.

Once the user is logged in you can navigate to the home page using "$location.path" by mentioning your required path.